# Permission popup does not show for Granular media permissions in android 13

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have upgraded project into sdk 33. My project has READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I have added Granular permission as per google docs. Issue is its not requesting for permission. permission popup doesn't appears. Following is my implemented code.

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.storagepermission">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

    <!-- Required to maintain app compatibility. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StoragePermission"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var button: Button

    private val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    private val permissionsFor13 = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO,
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO)

    fun permissions(): Array<String>? {
        val p: Array<String>
        p = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            Log.e("TAG", "permissions: permissionsFor13" )
            permissionsFor13
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "permissions: permission" )
            permissions
        }
        return p
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    private fun arePermissionsEnabled(): Boolean
    {
        for (permission in permissions()!!)
        {

            if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

                return false
        }

        return true
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    private fun requestMultiplePermissions()
    {
        val remainingPermissions = ArrayList<String>()
        for (permission in permissions()!!)
        {
            if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                remainingPermissions.add(permission)
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(33)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
             val readImagePermission = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES else Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, readImagePermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                arePermissionsEnabled()
            } else {
                requestMultiplePermissions()
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"permission Not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="311dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In requestMultiplePermissions() methods you are just checking whether the permission is granted or not and adding the permission to the remaining permission list. You have not called any method to actually request permission.

Check https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting for details